# Self Join Table with Itself Until 'Nulled' out

Tags: sql, database, powerbi, dax, self-join

I am looking for a way (using SQL or DAX) to self join a table with itself until it nulls out.
An example is probably the easiest way to describe the problem:
Suppose we have a reference table like this:

```
Name    Next Youngest Sibling
Aaron   Nicole
Nicole  Bobby
```

From this I would like to produce a join that flattens out this table like such:

```
Name    Next Sibling    Next X 2 Sibling    Next x 3 Sibling
Aaron   Nicole          Bobby               Null
Nicole  Bobby           Null                Null
Bobby   Null            Null                Null
```

Obviously this could be done via 3 manual joins but I am looking for a way to make this dynamic, so that it produces however many "Next x X" columns it needs in order to 'Null" out on every row in the result set.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Do you have any upper bound for number of siblings? One question - does it really (really) have to be in that output format? That's not going to be trivial because you'll need a dynamic pivot. If something like {Name, Sibling, Sibling Age Rank} would work you are looking at a much much easier query.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with [PATH() and PATHITEMREVERSE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/understanding-functions-for-parent-child-hierarchies-in-dax) functions in DAX.

[image: results]

To obtain the full path for each row:

```
All Names = PATH(People[Name], People[Next Youngest Sibling])
```

Which will be a pipe (`|`) delimited string; and it is in reversed order in this case because the sibling concept is the opposite of the default parent-child concept.

To obtain the `Next Sibling` and `Next X 2 Sibling`:

```
Next Sibling = PATHITEMREVERSE(People[All Names], 2)
Next X 2 Sibling = PATHITEMREVERSE(People[All Names], 3)
```

Where the lookup will be performed from the right of the path string.

Limitation: The end node also needs to be present in the table, hence the extra `Bobby, Bobby` row; otherwise the `PATH()` function will return an error.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do the pivoting yourself afterward, but you can create a columnar form of this along these lines in DAX:

```
Nulled = ADDCOLUMNS(
            CROSSJOIN(
                VALUES(Siblings[Name]),
                SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(1, COUNT(Siblings[Name])), "Nth", [Value])),
            "Sibling", LOOKUPVALUE(Siblings[Name],
                           Siblings[Rank], [Nth] + RANK.EQ([Name], Siblings[Name], ASC)),
            "Column", IF([Nth] = 1, "Next", "Next x " & [Nth]) & " Sibling")
```

This assumes you've added a `Rank` column to your original `Siblings` table.

---

The key here is doing the cross-join to get the table size you want and then define the `Sibling`.

[image: Unpivoted]

If you convert the nulls to empty strings, then this works nicely in a matrix visual where `Name` is on the rows and `Column` is on the columns. (Without replacing the nulls, the visual will not show the last row nor the last column since they are all blanks.)

[image: Matrix Visual]

Comment: Wow. You're truly a DAX master!